# How to get abstract syntax tree of a `c` program in `GCC`

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I  get the  abstract syntax tree of a c program in gcc?
I'm trying to automatically insert OpenMP pragmas to the input c program.
I need to analyze nested `for` loops for finding dependencies so that I can insert appropriate OpenMP pragmas.
So basically what I want to do is traverse and analyze the abstract syntax tree of the input c program.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: They say Clang is better suited for this task than GCC. I have not tried either though, so no guarantees.

Comment: But I need to use gcc only

Comment: @VishalVijay: This sounds like an artificial constraint. Why must you use only GCC?

Comment: If you're committed to GCC here's another possibility which is out of your reach but which otherwise might be helpful ... http://rosecompiler.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need full dataflow to find 'dependencies'.  Then you will need to actually *insert* the OpenMP calls.

What you want is a program transformation system.  GCC probably has the dependency information, but it is famously difficult to work with for custom projects.   Others have mentioned Clang and Rose.  Clang might be a decent choice, but custom analysis/transformation isn't its main purpose.   Rose is designed to support custom tools, but IMHO is a rather complicated scheme to use in practice because of its use of the EDG front end, which isn't designed to support transformation.

[THE FOLLOWING TEXT WAS DELETED BY A MODERATOR. I HAVE PUT IT BACK, BECAUSE IT IS ONE THE VALID TRANSFORMATION SYSTEMS FOR THIS TASK.  THE FACT THAT I AM RESPONSIBLE FOR IT IN NO WAY DIMINISHES ITS VALUE AS A USEFUL ANSWER TO THE OP.]

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit with its C front end is explicitly designed to be a program transformation system. It has full data flow analysis (including points-to analysis, call graph construction and range analyses) tied to the AST in sensible ways. It provides source-to-source rewrite rules enabling changes to the ASTs expressed in surface syntax form; you can read the transformations rather than inspect a bunch of procedural code. With a modified AST, DMS can regenerate source code including the comments in a compilable form.

Comment: The OP clearly states that he wants to use gcc only... That seems like a poor choice but that is his choice

Comment: @Ira Baxter thanks for the info. I will discuss about this with my team and get back to you later..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an AST but GCCXML might help http://linux.die.net/man/1/gccxml

edit : as stated by Ira Baxter gccxml does not output information about function/methods bodies. Here's a fork that seems to fix that lack http://sourceforge.net/projects/gccxml-bodies/

Comment: gccxml doesn't produce ASTs or in fact anything for the bodies of functions.  OP clearly wants ASTs of his loop code.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that.I edited the answer to point to a gccxml fork that dumps function bodies too.

Comment: OK, so how does he get dependences between computations using those ASTs?

Comment: Clearly not an easy task.I guess the product you promote will do the job just fine.

Comment: DMS has a variety of dependence analyses built-in, yes, and a framework for building others.   What OP wants to do isn't easy even with a good dependence analysis foundation.    IMHO, its probably hopeless if he starts without one.